# Scrapy - Dupefilter.py deprecated warning

Tags: scrapy, duplicates, scrapy-splash, deprecation-warning

When using this simple scrapy spider code:

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class BeerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'beer'

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.beerwulf.com/en-gb/c/mixedbeercases'

        yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        products = response.css('a.product.search-product.product-info-container.draught-product.notranslate.pack-product')
        for item in products:
            yield{
                'name': item.css('h4::text').get(),
                'price': item.css('span.price::text').get(),        
                }
```

I'm getting this warning:

```py
2023-04-03 10:58:53 [py.warnings] WARNING: C:\Users\chris\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy_splash\dupefilter.py:20: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function scrapy.utils.request.request_fingerprint().

If you are using this function in a Scrapy component, and you are OK with users of your component changing the fingerprinting algorithm through settings, use crawler.request_fingerprinter.fingerprint() instead in your Scrapy component (you can get the crawler object from the 'from_crawler' class method).

Otherwise, consider using the scrapy.utils.request.fingerprint() function instead.

Either way, the resulting fingerprints will be returned as bytes, not as a string, and they will also be different from those generated by 'request_fingerprint()'. Before you switch, make sure that you understand the consequences of this (e.g. cache invalidation) and are OK with them; otherwise, consider implementing your own function which returns the same fingerprints as the deprecated 'request_fingerprint()' function.
  fp = request_fingerprint(request, include_headers=include_headers)
```

The code seems to run fine but I wonder if the duplication filter is actually working as designed.

Comment: yes  - not sure how to update the code to prevent the warning.  I believe I want the user to be able to change the algorithm through settings but not sure how to implement the suggested code in using scrapy.

Comment: It is just a warning.  I suggest ignoring it unless you are certain it applies to you